# Azure Appservice crashes when adding DB Migration code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use code first and .NET core on an Azure App Service Web App

I have run the Add-Migration and Update-Database and when I run the app locally in VS2017 it updates the DB as expected

But when I add the following code to try and run that automatically in my AppService the app crashes with the error message Unable to start app

Here is the line I have added to my startup.cs

```
 using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
               serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<NWMposBackendContext>().Database.Migrate();

            }
```

As soon as I add that code the app fails to start, if I remove it the app works as expected.

Do I need to add/do something more to have Migrations be run when I pub lish the app to AppServices?

Answer (score 0):

setting the  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"`  in the appservice fixed the problem immediately, without that it could not find the correct connection string to migrate the DB to.